# apache2 upgrade - migrating the configuration file

Tags: apache2, apache2.2, apache2.4

i am currently upgrading my apache from 2.2.22 to 2.4 but still struggling with the configuration changes.

my apache 2.2 configuration:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
```

my apache 2.4 configuration:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
    Satisfy all
</Files>
```

I am not sure about the `Satisfy all` in my new 2.4 config. Is this configuration migrated correctly??

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one rule, `Satisfy all` is not needed at all (neither in Apache-2.2 nor in Apache-2.4). Otherwise the migration looks all right.